# Numpy: Transform sparse matrix to ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I really couldn't google it. How to transform sparse matrix to ndarray?

Assume, I have sparse matrix t of zeros. Then

```
g = t.todense()
g[:10] 

matrix([[0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0]])
```

instead of [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

**Solution:**

t.toarray().flatten()

Comment: you can use `.toarray()` instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.asarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html):

```
>>> a = np.asarray(g)
>>> a
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0]])
```

Where `g` is your dense matrix in the example (after calling `t.todense()`).

You specifically asked for the output of

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

which has only one dimension. To get that, you'll want to [`flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) the array:

```
>>> flat_array = np.asarray(g).flatten()
>>> flat_array
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

**Edit:**

You can skip straight to the array from the sparse matrix with:

```
a = t.toarray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Transpose your matrix to convert first column to first row

```
g = g.T
```